# Order results from a MySQL table by the number of occurrences from another table, if there are any

Tags: php, mysql, join

I know this question might have been asked, but I think this is slightly more complicated than what I found through the search function.

With a PHP code, I wish to order results from a MySQL table by the number of occurrences from another table, if there are any, in a **DESC** order.

Let me explain myself concretely.

I have two tables:

First table, called "post" with the following non-exhaustive content:

- id
- ...

Second table, called "post_votes" with the following non-exhaustive content:

- id
- post_id
- user_id
- ...

In reality: if a user votes for an existing post (the ones listed in the "post" table), a record is made in the "post_votes" table, inserting the post id as post_id and the user id as user_id.
There can therefore exist from 0 to several occurrences of the post, if multiple users voted for it, and this constitutes the amount of votes for a post.

Now, this is how I wish to order my results. I need to order the posts listed in the "post" table by their votes, i.e. by their number of occurrences from the "post_votes" table.

One thing to keep in mind though, some posts might never receive any vote, and 0 occurrence would be found in the second table, for instance.

I would appreciate any help on the topic!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) B where b.postid=a.ID) DESC` something like this would work for the 0 occurances too as they would receive 0 on the count and so all be at the bottom

Comment: Note joins as suggested below probably won't work as they won't return a record in your primary table if there isn't an entry for it in your secondary table. Though you'll need to test/check that

Comment: The sub-select posted above will work just needs changing to match your tables/columns properly

Comment: Thanks Dave! This works indeed.
Just a 'FROM' was missing.

At the end, with matching variables as shown in my original post, maybe it'll help others:
$post_req = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_votes WHERE post_votes.post_id = post.id) DESC');

Answer (score 1):

It could be with a single SQL query using [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) and [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html):

```
SELECT post.id, COUNT(post_votes.post_id) AS upvotes
FROM post, post_votes
WHERE post.id = post_votes.post_id
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY upvotes DESC
```

Not I cannot test the validity of this query at the moment but it is something along this lines.

Comment: Thanks, but it only works if values exist in the second table. If no occurrence is in that second table, the query returns only the posts which do have votes and forgets the ones with 0 vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Left Join

```
 select *,count(post_id) voteCount  from post left join post_votes on
    post.id=post_votes.post_id group by post_id order by voteCount desc
```