# How to order a Select query in MySQL based on the most occurrence of another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table and a memory table. The `product` table contains product ID and product name:

| product_id | product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | RAM |
| 2 | HDD |
| 3 | SSD |

The memory table contains different memory as below:

| memory_id | memory |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 128 GB |
| 2 | 256 GB |
| 3 | 512 GB |
| 4 | 1 TB |
| 5 | 8 GB |
| 6 | 16 GB |
| 7 | 32 GB |

I have created two drop-down select options for products and for memory and save them in a `cart` table as below:

| order_id | product_id | memory_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

I am wondering is there any way to do `DESC` order the select options for `memory` based on the occurrence of that specific `product_id` in `cart` table?
My target is to order the select options of the `memory` with the most used cases.

For example, my current select options for `memory` looks like:

```
<select name="memory" id="memory">
  <option value="1">128 GB</option>
  <option value="2">256 GB</option>
  <option value="3">512 GB</option>
  ...
</select>
```

But what I am looking for when I would select the product `2`, the select for `memory` will be:

```
<select name="memory" id="memory">
  <option value="3">512 GB</option>
  <option value="4">1 TB</option>
  <option value="1">128 GB</option>
  <option value="2">256 GB</option>
  <option value="5">8 GB</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I'm also wondering how would that impact on the query time, assuming that I have a `cart` table with thousands of rows.

Comment: What is the exact output you want to see here?

Comment: You can use subqueries, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358136/order-results-from-a-mysql-table-by-the-number-of-occurrences-from-another-table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I have added an example below.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by memory_id then order by count(*) DESC

```
SELECT memory_id 
FROM cart
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

If you want to fetch data for that select in one query,
You could join memory table then select memory_id and memory, and group by both fields.